# Flex - Use Variables for Object Attribute Names

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, object

How do you use variables to access Object attributes?

Suppose I have an Object declared as follows,

```
var obj:Object = new Object;
obj.Name = "MyName";
obj.Age = "10";
```

How would i do something like this,

```
var fieldName:String = "Name";
var fieldAge:String = "Age";
var Name_Age:String = obj.fieldName + " ," + obj.fieldAge;
```

The code above treats 'fieldName' and 'fieldAge' as attribute name itself.
I want to treat the same as a variable, and map the value associated with the variable as the Object attribute name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use square brackets like this:

```
var age:String = obj[fieldAge];
```

Comment: Thanks Mico.
Worked for me... 

I was using an array of Objects.. Hence used,
objArray[index][fieldName];