# String and value object

Tags: php, apache-flex

In php we can assign a method name to a variable and then use that variable to call the method. For example:

```
$image_create_func = 'ImageCreateFromGIF';
$newImage = $image_create_func($oldImage);
```

But can we do this in Flex?
In flex, I have the string

```
public var key:String = "email"
```

And I also have a value object searchTerm:SearchTermVO which has a public property "email" (searchTerm.email).
Now I want to do searchTerm.email by doing something like in php: searchTerm.key but it's not possible.
Can anybody help me with this plz?
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want to call a method of a class as a variable from another class?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  
I mean that can I access the value of the variable "key" (which is email) to call the public property "email" of the searchTerm, like searchTerm.email but by calling searchTerm.(value of key, which is email)? It is like the pointer I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the square brackets:

```
var email:String = SearchTErm[email];
```

Comment: I have found this answer, it can help to understand better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475569/flex-use-variables-for-object-attribute-names